# How to change alpha of a Shader in Unity by code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, gameobject

I have a GameObject with a material set to transparent, and I want to change its alpha to 80 instead of 255.
But I want to do it by code, not with the editor sliders.
Is there a simple way to change the alpha of a shader using just a line of code?
Something like:

```
MyObject.GetComponent<Material>().shader.alpha = 80;
```

I've looked around the internet and I've found only more complex solutions...

Comment: Look for `sharedMaterial` and `Material Property Blocks`, they help you changing the attributes of your material, which will reflect in the shader.

Comment: @Daniel I wrote 
            MyObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.SetFloat("color.a", 0.4f);
But I think I can only set a color or a float property, and the alpha is neither of those things, right? How do you think I can change it?

Comment: Alpha is a float between 0 and 1. If you are having problems with setting the alpha, you must remember to set the tags (`Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }`) and to set the correct blend type (`Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha`), otherwise your alpha won't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
public class SetAlpha : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material materialWithAlphaValue;

    public void ChangeAlphaValue(Color color)
    {
        materialWithAlphaValue.SetColor("_MY_COLOR_SHADER_VARIABLE_NAME", color);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
public class SetAlpha : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material materialWithAlphaValue;

    public void ChangeAlphaValue(float alpha)
    {
        var color = materialWithAlphaValue.GetColor("_MY_COLOR_SHADER_VARIABLE_NAME");
        materialWithAlphaValue.SetColor("_MY_COLOR_SHADER_VARIABLE_NAME", new Color(color.r, color.g, color.b, alpha));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Using `Material.Color` is the same as using `Material.GetColor("_Color");` this is the default naming for base colors in the standard unity shaders.

```
public void ChangeDefaultMatAlpha(float a)
{
    _MyMaterial.color = new Color(_MyMaterial.color.r, _MyMaterial.color.g _MyMaterial.color.b,
        a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But you propose to assign a new color, instead of changing just the alpha of the existing one, right?

Comment: @Alessandro Yes! Thats what i did, but you can copy the original r,g,b values then assign a custom a value, i think there is a method called GetColor() :)

Comment: thank you, that last one works fine! But I had to change the color option from RGB 0-255 to RGB 0-1, otherwise it had a strange effect, like infrared vision... Weird! :D